# Weekly Featured Image - should late votes count?

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

It seems to me that there was a mistake made when selecting [featured image for current week](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1417/weekly-featured-image-sept-5-11). The last two (deciding) votes have been cast after voting deadline - see [current winner's reputation history](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1209/intothewild?tab=reputation).

Since voting deadline is the only rule written in large friendly letters, I think it should be honoured when counting votes [as the community seems to have agreed](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/628/lets-have-well-defined-submission-and-voting-periods-for-the-featured-image-thre).

I think this kind of problem can only occur if the top images are scoring very close, in which case their votes should undergo a closer inspection.

Perhaps the results should be fixed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To resolve *this weeks issue*:

I'm personally open to extending this week's contest out an additional week and having bluetooth up this week and mark's photo next week. Given that it wasn't the other photo's fault and all. We can just have an extra long contest this time.  I'm against this as a general in-the-future tie breaker though, since it throws the contest schedule out of whack.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like a great solution to me. :) I've added a lengthier comment on my earlier reply.

Comment: We might want to at least close the thread to submissions after a week. Otherwise, I think we'll have some large differences between early submissions and late submissions from a votes standpoint.

Comment: @Mark this is what we'll be doing then.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty disappointed. The "Voting closes" notice in the voting thread couldn't be any clearer: my image won this week according to the rules. :(

Comment: Wow... that is rotten. You clearly had won for at least 24 hours I thought after voting closed.

Comment: Wow, sorry about that - I was on vacation and by the time I got back on Monday, the mods hadn't updated the PotW - so I just clicked to accept the answer whoever was the winner was *at that moment*.  I then reminded them to update the PotW and they ran with it.  Twas an honest mistake on a close vote.  There's nothing *I* can do, a mod will have to weigh in.

Comment: Hope my comment did not sound too harsh either. I appreciate the work, just crummy that it happened. And do not want to take from the other picture, just agreed that it was too bad this happened.

Comment: @IPX No worries - it is crummy that it happened. I'm *personally* open to extending **this week's contest** out an additional week and having bluetooth up this week and mark's photo next week.  Given that it wasn't the other photo's fault and all.  We can just have an extra long contest this time.  But I don't know how the rest of the community feels.

Comment: I think that works... it was a short week anyway this week.

Comment: Yikes! I see lots of conversation has occurred since I fired off my quick reply earlier! Thanks IPX for fighting my corner, and rfusca for your responses. Reading it again, my original message sounds pretty grumpy so let me add that (a) hey, worse things happen and (b) Bluetooth is a great photo! It was neck and neck all week and I don't want to spoil the buzz intothewild must have seeing it up there. It looks great. rfusca's suggestion of extending this week's comp works fine for me. Thanks again, guys. :)

Comment: I did note that there was a tie at the time I updated the header. I think @rfusca's idea of extending the contest this week, and exhibiting both photos, one this week and one next, is a fair resolution. The holiday interfered a bit with the closing period, as I did not get to it until Monday evening (having been off in the mountains the whole extended weekend.)

Answer (score 0):

Late votes *shouldn't* count, but there will be occasions where votes are cast between the official end time and when a moderator wakes up the following morning to close the question/update the banner/etc.

One possible solution would be to adjust the end time to be more moderator friendly (for example, 6:00 UTC on Sundays would suit *me*; also one of the quietest times on the chat room - of course there are other moderators that also need to be responsible for updating the banner, setting the new thread, etc.).

Comment: I thought about changing the time as well, but the timezone thing threw me off.

Comment: Checking for late votes is not something you'd have to do every week, only the rare ones when there is close race. That need would still apply if the time is changed, unless you really hit the page at the right minute.

Comment: @rfusca I figured that I get up early on Sunday, and could do it most weekends when most people are still in bed

Comment: I've set several alarms for myself, a little ahead of voting closure. I think by simply being a bit more diligent, we can prevent any problems with late votes by locking the threads at the right time. I'm usually up at time, and I intend to make sure that the PotW threads are locked on time.